# Match url pattern for blog article

Tags: regex

I am looking to match all urls in a database with the following structure:

```
/blogs/author/title
```

I don't want to match any of the strings below:

```
 /blogs
 /blogs/
 /blogs/author
 /blogs/author/
```

not sure how to construct the required regex. thx

Comment: `^\/blogs\/.*\/.*$` http://rubular.com/r/61IqXwis28, yes, I did vote to close.

Comment: the author name and title are variables that change

Comment: @MattClark: it still matches empty author and/or title, throw some `+`es there.

Comment: Then ask the right question. My regex matches what you provided for samples. Show us what you have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If blogs/author should be in every url, use

```
^\/blogs\/author\/\w+$
```

or

```
^\/\w+\/\w+\/\w+$
```

for any url that has 3 "parameters"

or

```
^\/blogs\/\w+\/\w+$
```

for any blogs/... urls

Answer (score 0):

Blog article URL pattern:

```
"URL":"((?:https?\\:\/\/|www\\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)/i"
```